# Make DIV bigger if scrolled

Tags: html, css, height

Is it possible to make DIV bigger when content of the page is scrolled? I have chatbox with position:fixed on the right side of my page. My CSS for the chat box is height:100% right:0 bottom:0 top:50px. The top:50px is because I don't want it to hide the navigation bar on top of my page. Now the problem is, that when I start scrolling the page, the navigation bar obviously disappear from sight and there is 50px high blank space on top of my chatbox. What I want is that when I start scrolling the page, the chatbox should take the whole 100% of the screen, so that there is no blank space on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

you may do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(window).scroll(function () {
         if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
             $('.chat_box').css({top:'0px'});
         }
         else {
             $('.chat_box').css({top:'10px'});
         }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5tnygmrz/1/

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/cq1e8c1t/

i think you will need javascript

```
window.onscroll = function (e) {
    var topscroll = window.scrollY
    if (topscroll > 50) {
        document.getElementById('fixed').style.top = 0
    } else {
        document.getElementById('fixed').style.top = 50 + 'px'
    }
}
```